# change function return signature from optional param

Tags: typescript, overloading

This is my sample code:

```js
type base = {
    a: string;
};

type base_plus = {
    foo: string;
};

const get = (param?: number) => {
    const newBase: base = { a: '1' };

    if (param) {
        return { ...newBase, foo: 'bar' } as base_plus;
    }
    return newBase;
};
```

What I want is this:

```js
const a = get(1); // => a is of type base_plus
const b = get(); // => b is of type base
```

i.e to be able to know the return type of the get() function directly from the fact if i'm calling with the optional parameter or no

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would you like to declare overloads function like this?

```js
type base = {
    a: string;
};

type base_plus = {
    foo: string;
};

function get(param: number): base_plus;

function get():base;

function get(param?: number) {
    const newBase: base = { a: '1' };

    if (param) {
        return { ...newBase, foo: 'bar' } as base_plus;
    }

    return newBase;
};

const a = get(1); // => a is of type base_plus
const b = get();
```

Checkout this [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBARghgZ2gXigbwFBW1OAuKBYAJwEsA7AcwG4MBfWjUSWRCAfTABsBXBKVJhxQAZgHsxBImSq0GGDCJ7kAxsFJjyUShGAAKMHGJwAtgXI8TMCMQCUBeEk68EjJavWbtuvfccQ3ZTUNLR19Q2MTAH5zS2s7dCwcFU0iKHIIAHcAITYHNgF0XAIAcgBGEqh5JOxSESgDI1NbROFhYl0eYi00KAA6AYyctgAaUQlS%20GJKulx%20f2c%20WmE6BXbO7vSs3KQ5RhTyNLhCsL0y22ooAHorgQA%20XChSfjF65mgF7j4MA7SYE58FyAA)